# Accessing Linksys WAP4400N setup utility

Tags: networking, security, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I've got the aforementioned access point and I'm trying to use it to extend my wireless coverage. There is a Netgear ADSL modem and router sitting first, but I'm slightly too far from it to get a good signal so I've got an ethernet cable dragged and I'm connecting it to the access point.

It connects, but the problem is that the network is not secured and I don't know how to access the setup utility to change it. I did RTFM, but the default IP given there doesn't work. Is there a way to find out what IP I should use?

I should also add, that I don't have credentials to access the Netgear's setup (it's a shared accommodation and the admin is unreachable), so I can't see connected devices and their IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to configure the access point by connecting it directly to your computer using a crossover tp cable. If you set a static ip on your computer that matches the ip range of the access point.

Do all the configuration of the AP and then reconnect it to the network and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

If your PC is connected with the wireless access point, you can see what is the router's IP-address by issuing an `ipconfig` in a command prompt. The IP listed under "Default Gateway" of your wireless connection should be the router's address.
You can then put `http://<ip-address found>` in the address bar of your browser to access the configuration utility.

Comment: As far as I know that's router's IP (the Netgear that's on the top) and it's already set up with a password. However, my access point (Linksys) makes a hole in this security by creating an open network - that's what I'm trying to fix.

Comment: @maciej: Ah Ok, then I suppose you have to go the way @Pär describes